# Migraciones en Laravel 5: diferencia entre timestamps y nullableTimestamps

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

En la documentación de las [migraciones en Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations) indica:

```
$table->timestamps();
// Adds nullable created_at and  updated_at TIMESTAMP equivalent columns.

$table->nullableTimestamps();
// Alias of timestamps() method.
```

Por lo que supongo que no hay diferencia entre usar uno y otro y el segundo habrá quedado de versiones antiguas por compatibilidad o algún otro motivo.

Comment: es un alias y es lo mismo... cual es la pregunta exacta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el código de Laravel, vemos que no hay ninguna diferencia, `nullableTimestamps()` llama a `timestamps()` con los mismos parámetros de entrada, sin embargo yo utilizo `timestamps()`, es más cortos y es una instrucción menos de código (aunque sabemos que esto es despreciable en términos de tiempo).

```
/**
 * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * @param  int  $precision
 * @return void
 */
public function timestamps($precision = 0)
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->nullable();

    $this->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->nullable();
}

/**
 * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * Alias for self::timestamps().
 *
 * @param  int  $precision
 * @return void
 */
public function nullableTimestamps($precision = 0)
{
    $this->timestamps($precision);
}
```

Para más información del código, revisa: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L953

---

Respondiendo a si existía alguna diferencia en versiones anteriores, la respuesta es sí, en Laravel 5.1 `nullableTimestamps()` creaba campos que permitían valores null, mientras `timestamps()`, no:

```
/**
 * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function nullableTimestamps()
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    $this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
}
/**
 * Add creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function timestamps()
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at');
    $this->timestamp('updated_at');
}
```

Para más información de este código de Laravel 5.1: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L775